# Unable to merge dex Android studio 3.0

Tags: android, android-studio, dex

I have some problem with my project. In Android studio 2.3.3 it works fine but when I updated to 3.0 I have problem to marge dex.

I clean and rebuild project.

What is wrong:

> Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
>   com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

StackTrace:

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
at     org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeA  ctions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
at   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(  ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
at    org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(Sk  ipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:63)
at   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecut  er.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
at   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(Vali  datingTaskExecuter.java:58)
at   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.ex  ecute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
at   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
at   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execu  te(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
at   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(Skip  OnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
at   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execu  te(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
at   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(  CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
at   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWork  er$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
at   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOpe  rationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
at   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOpe  rationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
at   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultB  uildOperationExecutor.java:197)
at   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuild  OperationExecutor.java:107)
at   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWork  er.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
at   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWork  er.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
at   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.p  rocessTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:124)
at   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:80)
at   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1  .execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:105)
at   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1  .execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
at   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTask  ExecutionPlan.java:625)
at   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(Def  aultTaskExecutionPlan.java:580)
at   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.r  un(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
at   org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExec  ute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
at   org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImp  l.java:46)
at   org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(  ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException:   com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex
at   com.android.builder.dexing.DxDexArchiveMerger.mergeMultidex(DxDexArchiveMer ger.java:266)
at  com.android.builder.dexing.DxDexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(DxDexArchive Merger.java:133)
at  com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexMergerTransformCallable.cal l(DexMergerTransformCallable.java:97)
at   com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.ExternalLibsMergerTransform.tr  ansform(ExternalLibsMergerTransform.kt:121)
at   com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTa  sk.java:222)
at   com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTa  sk.java:218)
at   com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
at   com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(Transfor  mTask.java:213)
at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
at   org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$Incre  mentalTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:173)
at   org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$Stand  ardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134)
at   org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$Stand  ardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:121)
at   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(Ex  ecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:122)
at   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOpe  rationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
at   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOpe  rationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
at   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultB  uildOperationExecutor.java:197)
at   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuild  OperationExecutor.java:107)
at   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeA  ction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:111)
at   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeA  ctions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
... 27 more
Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable     to merge dex
at com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerCallable.call(DexArchiveMergerCa llable.java:72)
at   com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerCallable.call(DexArchiveMergerCa  llable.java:36)
... 46 more
Caused by: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define     Landroid/support/v4/view/accessibility/AccessibilityRecordCompatIcsMr1;
at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:661)
at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:616)
at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:598)
at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:198)
at   com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerCallable.call(DexArchiveMergerCa  llable.java:61)
... 47 more
```

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "...."
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 2
    multiDexEnabled true
    versionName "1.01"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),      'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}
repositories {
mavenCentral()

maven { url 'http://maven.livotovlabs.pro/content/groups/public' }
}
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.3'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1' //1.0.1
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87' //6.5.87
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'Parse-*.jar')
compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0'
compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-applinks:1.4.0'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.0'
compile 'it.neokree:MaterialNavigationDrawer:1.3.3'
compile 'com.github.navasmdc:MaterialDesign:1.5@aar'
compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
compile 'com.github.bluejamesbond:textjustify-android:2.1.0'
compile 'it.neokree:MaterialTabs:0.11'
compile('com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.1') {
    exclude module: 'junit'
}
compile ('eu.livotov.labs.android:CAMView:2.0.1@aar') {transitive=true}
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
}
```

When i delete multiDexEnable:

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:63)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:124)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:80)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:105)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:625)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:580)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex
at com.android.builder.dexing.DxDexArchiveMerger.mergeMonoDex(DxDexArchiveMerger.java:177)
at com.android.builder.dexing.DxDexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(DxDexArchiveMerger.java:118)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexMergerTransformCallable.call(DexMergerTransformCallable.java:97)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.ExternalLibsMergerTransform.transform(ExternalLibsMergerTransform.kt:121)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:222)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:218)
at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:213)
at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:173)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:121)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:122)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:111)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
... 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex
at com.android.builder.dexing.DxDexArchiveMerger.lambda$mergeMonoDex$0(DxDexArchiveMerger.java:171)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex
Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex
at com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerCallable.call(DexArchiveMergerCallable.java:72)
at com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerCallable.call(DexArchiveMergerCallable.java:36)
Caused by: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define   Landroid/support/v4/view/accessibility/AccessibilityRecordCompatIcsMr1;
at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:661)
at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:616)
at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:598)
at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:198)
at   com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerCallable.call(DexArchiveMergerCa  llable.java:61)
... 1 more
```

Comment: did you already try without multidex?

Comment: yes. I'm trying to run app in Android Studio 2.3.3 and it works. So it is problem only when im using 3.0 version

Comment: Just a guess, but I think it's related to duplication of dependencies. because this problem occurs a lot since everybody is updating to Android Studio 3.0. e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47086275/trying-to-build-android-project-with-glide-package-throws-unable-to-merge-dex). My guess was if you turn off the multidex lib, you might see a better stack trace, showing the duplication error.

Answer (score 3):

This is related to duplicated dependencies in your project. There is a duplicate dependency which is happened because some libraries is implicitly dependent to the same library but with different version. Gradle 4.1 which is used in the Android Studio is not forgiving for library duplication.

You can check it from dependencies tree with the following command in your terminal in Linux (**app** is your module name):

```
./gradlew app:dependencies
```

or if you're using Windows try this in command prompt:

```
gradlew.bat app:dependencies
```

Then after you found it, you need to exclude it from the library and use only one of them. Something like this:

```
compile('com.library.name:version') {
  // this is a case for duplicate support library version.
  exclude group: 'com.android.support'
  exclude module: 'appcompat-v7'
}
```

Be noted that you are better to use the same version of 
`compileSdkVersion`, `buildToolsVersion`, `targetSdkVersion`, and `Support Library`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was related to dependency issue with gson given by awsgateway sdk and the gson already present.

```
gradle -q app:dependencies
```

Didn't show any differences in the dependencies, but the gradle build stack trace showed it was something related to gson.
 Caused by: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/gson/FieldNamingStrategy;

Following this [issue](https://github.com/ManifestWebDesign/twitter-connect-plugin/issues/53), I added below config to build.gradle but that didn't fix the issue.

```
compile("com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3") {
    exclude module: 'gson:2.2.4'
}
```

I had to manually remove the jar(gson-2.2.4.jar given by apigateway during sdk generation) present in the app/libs folder.

Answer (score -2):

i face the same problem then i found the solution from [Here (Github)](https://github.com/square/leakcanary/issues/815)

Add

```
multiDexEnabled true
```

in Your Default Configuration 
exemple

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "my application id "
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName '1.0'
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

then Add

```
implementation('commons-validator:commons-validator:1.4.1') {
    exclude group: 'commons-collections', module: 'commons-collections'
}
```

in your dependencies. 
It's work for me i hope it's also slution your problem :)

Comment: Why you think that the OPs question and your problem (or that of the LeakCanary list) are "the same"? And why do you suggest adding `multiDexEnabled true` to the OPs default config, when it is already there? And finally, why do you suggest the OP adding a library without giving a reason to do so?

Comment: i suggest because i follow the answer but it doesn't work for me. i thoughts other people maybe face the same problem that's why i shear how do i solve this problem.